# How to fix "Error: data and hash arguments required"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt, bcrypt

Good day developers, I am new in backend technology with nodejs and mongodb as my database, I am currently working on a project that involves creating a signup and a login features and i have problem with the login process and i will appreciate help here.

this is my server code:

```
const express = require("express")
const {default:mongoose} = require("mongoose")
const app = express();
const Blog = require("./models/blog.js")
const User = require("./models/User.js")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const JWT = require("jsonwebtoken")
const cookies = require("cookie-parser")
const cookieJwtAuth = require("./cookieAuth.js")

app.set("views engine", "ejs")
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fitnesblog").
then(()=>{console.log("Mongoose server has Started")
})
.catch(()=>{
    console.log("Unsuccessful")
})

app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(cookies())

app.post("/blogs/login",async(req,res)=>{
    const {Email,Password} = req.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({Email})

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(Password, user.Password);

    if (!isMatch){
        return res.redirect("/blogs/signup")
    }

    const payload = {
        User: {
            Email:User.Email,
        },
    }

    const token = await JWT.sign(payload,"thisismysecretkey",{
        expiresIn:"3600",
    })

    res.cookie("token",token,{
        httpOnly: true,
    })

    res.redirect("/blogs/create")


})

})
app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log("server currently running on port 5000")
})
```

this is the response i do receive:

```
C:\Users\go\Desktop\ejs\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:208
        error = new Error('data and hash arguments required');
                ^

Error: data and hash arguments required
    at Object.compare (C:\Users\go\Desktop\ejs\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:208:17)
    at C:\Users\go\Desktop\ejs\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:29:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.module.exports.promise (C:\Users\go\Desktop\ejs\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:20:12)
    at Object.compare (C:\Users\go\Desktop\ejs\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:204:25)
    at C:\Users\go\Desktop\ejs\app.js:130:34
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Either `Password`, `user.Password` is `undefined`

Comment: I tried in another way bt yet no solution

Answer (score -1):

Try this, worked for me:

Wrap your password and `user.password` to String

```
const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(String(Password), String(user.Password));
```

Comment: Thanks Satvik, it worked but it always goes back to my signup page even after registering the user.